# How to write inside input after making it editable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Am populating values of my input field from JSON data what am getting from back-end, now there is an edit button on UI by on click on that button I am enabling my input field but not able to type inside as I am setting some value

I want to write inside the input once I have made them editable.

```
const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const [disabled, setdisabled] = useState(false);
  const [editBtn, seteditBtn] = useState(true);
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {editBtn === true && (
          <div align="right">
            <button
              className="btn white_color_btn"
              type="button"
              onClick={edit}
            >
              Edit
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
        {editBtn === false && (
          <button className="btn white_color_btn" type="submit">
            Save
          </button>
        )}

        <div className="row">
          <div className="form-group col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              disable
              id="firstName"
              name="firstName"
              value={dataItems.firstname}
              disabled={disabled ? "" : "disabled"}
              ref={register({ required: true })}
            />
            {errors.firstname && (
              <span className="text-danger">first name required</span>
            )}
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="emp_designation">First name</label>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              disabled
              id="lastname"
              name="lastname"
              value={dataItems.lastname}
              disabled={disabled ? "" : "disabled"}
              ref={register({ required: true })}
            />
            {errors.lastname && (
              <span className="text-danger">last name required</span>
            )}
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="lastname">Lastname</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

**On click of edit**

```
    const edit = () => {
    setdisabled(true);
  };
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-architecture-3dc3m?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: When you state that you are getting the value from backend, do you actuallly make an API call to get data in the same component or in another component. Also onClick of submit you would require to submit data to backend and still hold the state in form right?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yup I am getting data from backend in the same component I am checking if user is allowed to edit, then only showing edit button then on click making it to change save, yes on click of save want to save data to server(back-end)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I am using `graphql` to fetch apis, and on submit in graphql There is a method `refetchQueries` by which I will run the query which is populating the data and will populate my UI with latest changes

Comment: Added an answer with your respective query. Let me know if you need any more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the input editable, you need to update a local state which controlls the input value. As suggested by you in the comments, you are using graphql to get the data, you can make use of useEffect to set the data in state and then on click of edit, update the localState

```
export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const [disabled, setdisabled] = useState(true);
  const [editBtn, seteditBtn] = useState(true);
  const { loading, data } = useQuery("some qraphql query here"); // getting data from graphql
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setFormData(data);
  }, [data]);

  const edit = () => {
    setdisabled(false);
    seteditBtn(false);
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    console.log(formData);
    // submit data using formData state.
  };

  const handleChange = e => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    console.log(name, value);
    setFormData(prev => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {editBtn === true && (
          <div align="right">
            <button
              className="btn white_color_btn"
              type="button"
              onClick={edit}
            >
              Edit
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
        {editBtn === false && (
          <button className="btn white_color_btn" type="submit">
            Save
          </button>
        )}

        <div className="row">
          <div className="form-group col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="firstname"
              name="firstname"
              onChange={handleChange}
              value={formData.firstname}
              disabled={disabled}
              ref={register({ required: true })}
            />
            {errors.firstname && (
              <span className="text-danger">first name required</span>
            )}
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="emp_designation">First name</label>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              id="lastname"
              name="lastname"
              value={formData.lastname}
              onChange={handleChange}
              disabled={disabled}
              ref={register({ required: true })}
            />
            {errors.lastname && (
              <span className="text-danger">last name required</span>
            )}
            <br />
            <label htmlFor="lastname">Lastname</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Working mock demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-goldwasser-dem6j?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Considering the logic is mostly determined by how you fetch the data, providing a codesandbox is a little tricky. But I can surely add a mock demo. But the above code in the post should be sufficient for you to edit your original code

Comment: Ya I got it, no need to show demo, Now useEffect will take care of what I was struggling in,let me test this out with my real api

Comment: Added a mock demo in any case, there were certain typos here and here in your original codesandbox. Updated that with the useEffect logic

Comment: hey you there, I have an issue

Comment: Let me know the issue Dheeraj

Comment: hey I am getting data from `graphql` like this `{
  "getData": {
    "firstName": "steve",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "__typename": "EmployeePositionDept"
  }
}`    so I want to set formdata like setformdata(data.getData), because it is taking null empty for now, my use effect is   `useEffect(() => {
    if(!data) return
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    setFormData(data);
}, [data])`

Comment: When I am doing console in form so first it shows empty then it shows the data, if I am doing  `value={formData.getData.firstName}` it throws error as formData.getData is not defined'

Answer (score 3):

Your input is controlled by the value you are giving to it. ie: Its value is always for example `empData.item.name`.

And you are not providing a change handler to handle the change.

Try adding something like this:

```
function myChangeHandler(e){
  setEditedValueSomeHow(e.target.value);
}

<input
  // ...
  onChange={myChangeHandler}
/>
```

Read more about [uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

PS: you should have had a warning message in your console like this one:[image]

**Edit:**

You are using `react-hook-form` to manage your form but at the same time giving values to your inputs.

Please refer to [this link](https://react-hook-form.com/faqs#Howtoinitializeformvalues) to initialize your form values.

short story:

1. Remove value form your input.
2. Pass an object to `useForm` hook containing initial values.

```
const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: "steve",
      lastname: "smith"
    }
  });
```

Here is a [working fork for your codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-haibt-jeruh)

Comment: Hey this will not help me because I have to define useForm hook at the top level and my data is coming after that, for mor clarification i  am using   `react-apollo-graphql` to fetch data so i have to check error and loading first after that I am getting data so if i initialize data in use form it will be undefined  or if i define my useForm after loading and error it will throw error as React Hook "useForm" is called conditionally

Comment: Then you have two choices: 1. Write your own form management. 2. Separate two components: One with error and initial state (not loaded) and the other when you have the data

Comment: :( I have to do this in this way only, will google around and find something

Comment: Hey I got your answer I have to do in this way only, but want to clarify one thing,now you are inserting valies using defaultValues in use form but at that time I have no data so can I use `useEffect` so when data is loaded from background (API) then I can pass values in useForm, please guide once

Comment: Yes I understand this case and I don't know if react-hook-form provide an imperative way to alter the values, I suggested that you do two components: - NoDataComponent and a WithDataComponent, the withDataComponent initialize useForm with default values that it receives from props. I think this way you'll avoid needing to alter the initialized useForm values

Comment: can you help me with one example

Comment: I updated my codesandbox, the NoDataComponent displays only "loading..." for example, it could render anything, even a form like the yours but with empty data
I just a timeout of 3 seconds to change the data

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your input as a controlled component and write onChange handlers which will update the state. This will allow you to edit the input field values. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-o5z2jf)

```
const [disabled, setdisabled] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState(empData.item.name) // setting default name 
  const [lastname, setLastname] = useState(empData.item.lastname) // default lastname

  const edit = () => {
    setdisabled(true);
  };

  return (<div className="container-fluid">
    <div align="right">
      <button className="btn" onClick={edit}>
        Edit
      </button>
    </div>
    <div className="row">
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          disable
          id="item.value"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setName(e.target.value)
          }}
          disabled={disabled ? "" : "disabled"}
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          disabled
          id={"lastname"}
          value={lastname}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setLastname(e.target.value)
          }}
          disabled={disabled ? "" : "disabled"}
        />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="lastname">Lastname</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>);
```

Comment: I cannot provide state initially because I am defining my state using hooks at top level and  my data is coming after that so it cant be done that way.wait Ill edit my post with codesand box link